# Get char from data value in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with value: 15.09.2012. How can I get (using Excel formula) each char from it?
For example in c# I will take char array and then get element by index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string is in `A1` and index number is in `A2`

```
=MID(A1, A2, 1)
```